Better form for integral$ \int_1^\infty 1/ (x \sqrt{x^2 - 1}) \exp(- a x)$
The definite integral
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2 -1 }} e^{-a x} dx $$
with parameter $a > 0$, doesn't have a solution in terms of elementary functions. I've tried using Mathematica's own integrator as well as Rubi, and looking in G&R. (This integral is somewhat similar to G&R 3.389-1 and -2, but trying to evaluate those did not work; the Meijer-G function is not defined for $n=1$.).
Mathematica permits the related integral
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^n \sqrt{x^2 -1 }} e^{-a x} \, dx & =\\
& -\frac{a 2^{n-2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_2\left(1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{n}{2};\frac{a^2}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (n)} \\
& + a^n \Gamma (-n) _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}+1;\frac{a^2}{4}\right) + \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}
with the restriction that $n < 1$; but we want $n = 1$ here.
Taking the limit $n \to 1$ yields the form
\begin{align}
& \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{a}{2} \left(2 \log (a)+3 \gamma -2+\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \, _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2};1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{a^2}{4}\right) \\
& + \frac{a}{2} \text{HypergeometricPFQ}^{(\{0\},\{0,1\},0)}\left(\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{1,\frac{3}{2}\right\},\frac{a^2}{4}\right) \\
& + a\,\text{HypergeometricPFQ}^{(\{0\},\{1,0\},0)}\left(\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{1,\frac{3}{2}\right\},\frac{a^2}{4}\right) \\ 
& + \frac{a}{2} \text{HypergeometricPFQ}^{(\{1\},\{0,0\},0)}\left(\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{1,\frac{3}{2}\right\},\frac{a^2}{4}\right) \\
\end{align}
where the $\text{HypergeometricPFQ}^\left(\{ 0 \},\{1,0\},0\right)$ and so on are derivatives of $_1F_2$ with respect to the parameters.
This is well enough behaved numerically, and matches a numerical evaluation of the original integral! Is there any way to write this without using derivatives (with respect to the parameters) of the hypergeometric functions?

A first change of variables y = (x - 1) yields
$$
e^{-a} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-a y}}{(y + 1)\sqrt{y^2 + 2 y}} \; dy.
$$
Mathematica can't do this integral, but Gradshteyn & Ryzhik can: see integral 3.367:
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\mu x} \; dx}{\left(1 + \cos t + x\right)\sqrt{x^2 + 2x}} = \frac{\exp\left(2\mu \cos^2 \frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sin{t}} \left(t - \sin t \int_0^\mu K_0(v) e^{-v \cos t}\; dv\right)\;$$
Here $\cos t = 0$ so take $t = \pi/2$. Then,
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}e^{- a x} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int_0^a K_0(v)\;dv.
$$
Mathematica can express the latter integral in terms of BesselK and StruveL (modified Struve) functions: finally,
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}e^{- a x} = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(1 - a\,\mathbf{L}_{-1}(a) K_0(a) - a \,\mathbf{L}_0(a) K_1(a)\right).
$$

I will also note that Sympy's integrate applied to the original integral yields a Meijer G-function.
